# Difference between declaring variables

Tags: java

I am a little confused in declaring variable in android, I know two ways of doing it.

```
   1. int EC, CC, PT, HC = 1;
   2. int EC = 1, CC = 1, PT = 1, HC = 1;
```

I want to know the difference between 1 & 2.

Are both the ways same ?

Comment: In 1st example, only HC will have value of 1, other will be default, in this case 0.

Comment: This is a Java thing, not an android specific thing.

Comment: It's interesting that no one mentions that both methods are a bad idea. Each variable should be declared on its own line, independent of the others, i.e. `int EC = 0; int CC = 0;`, etc.

Comment: @Alex, EC, CC, PT are uninitialized and not 0.

Comment: @SteveKuo: For local variables, yes, I stand corrected. :) Question does not define intended type, so I presumed to be class level fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not really related to Android, it is only dependent on Java.
Anyway,
the first approach creates the variables `EC, CC, PT` and `HC`. `HC` gets the value 1.
In the second approach you create all the variables and give them the value 1.

Just do a search for Java and Variables if you want to find some information about the subject. Here are two links for you:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html
http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/variables-in-java.shtml

On a side note, you should follow the Java naming conventions and keep your variables lowercase, or capitalize the first letter of any subsequent words in your variable name.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same.

In the first case, only `HC` will have the value 1 assigned.  The other variables will be left unassigned.

If these are instance or static variables, that means they will get the default value 0.  If they are local variables, you will need to assign them before you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

1. only HC will be initialized
2. all variables will be initialized (with value 1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming instance variables, frst way, EC,CC,PT are ZERO. Second way all are ONE.

Instance variables are assigned to default values, if nothing assigned.

If you define first one as local variable (inside any method), you will get compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, except EC, all are uninitialized.

In second case, all are initialized.

Comment: "unintialized" `int`s (and other primitives) are set to 0 (or false, 0f, whatever applies).

Comment: ... only if they are instance variables (variables declared inside the class but not inside a method)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the first 3 variables are uninitialized, that means when object is created compiler will initialize those uninitialize variables with the default values hich is ZERO in case of integer type and the last variable will be initialized with ONE.

In the second case each variable will be initialized with ONE. You can also do it as follows

First declare all variables

```
int EC, CC, PT, HC;
```

Then assign value

```
EC =CC =  PT =  HC = 1;
```

Comment: Assuming these are variables and not fields, in the first case EC, CC, PT are uninitialized, which is different than being assigned with 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `int EC,CC,PT,HC=1;`

```
The values for EC,CC and PT are Zero(0) and HC value is 1,
```

If you decalre `int EC=1,CC=1,PT=1,HC=1` means all  EC,CC,PT and HC values are one.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is like :
int EC;int CC;int PT;int HC = 1; // and only hc gets the value of 1
 The second example is like :
int EC=1;int CC=1;int PT=1;int HC = 1; // all of the vars get the value of 1